# Need to convert first worksheet in XML file to data.frame

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file, if I open it in excel there are two worksheets. I know that it has 3 nodes, style and the two worksheets. I've been trying to convert the first worksheet to a data.frame for a few hours now but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The first worksheet's name is PD Analysis.

```
library(xml2)

pg <- read_xml("/Users/lucychen/Documents/Lab/NIH 
lab/Data/exportedTest.xml")

# get all the <record>s
recs <- xml_find_all(pg, "PD Analysis")
print("here")
# extract and clean all the columns
vals <- trimws(xml_text(recs))

# extract and clean (if needed) the area names
labs <- trimws(xml_attr(recs, "label"))

# mine the column names from the two variable descriptions
# this XPath construct lets us grab either the <categ…> or <real…> tags
# and then grabs the 'name' attribute of them
cols <- xml_attr(xml_find_all(pg, "//data/variables/*[self::categoricalvariable or
                              self::realvariable]"), "name")

# this converts each set of <record> columns to a data frame
# after first converting each row to numeric and assigning
# names to each column (making it easier to do the matrix to data frame conv)
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(vals, "\ +"),
                             function(x) {
                               data.frame(rbind(setNames(as.numeric(x),cols)))
                             }))

# then assign the area name column to the data frame
dat$area_name <- labs

print(dat)
```

Here is an example of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="b1">
            <Font ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="c1">
            <Interior ss:Color="#FFFF00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="c2">
            <Interior ss:Color="#00FFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="PD Analysis">
        <Table>
            <Row ss:StyleID="b1">
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">File</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">SegmNo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">SegmName</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EventNo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EventName</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EventXDAT</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">sample_#</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">time_secs</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">pupil_diam</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">scaled_pupil_diam</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">xdat</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">blink</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">interpolated</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Data1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">segment 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">event 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
```

Comment: Is it actually an xlsx (which is XML internally) document? If so, [readxl](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) or the like should work. Otherwise, it's likely going to be a lot more work, and this isn't really going to be an answerable question without your data.

Comment: It is not an xlsx, is there an easy way to convert it?

Comment: If Excel can open it, I suspect it may just have the wrong file extension. Regardless, if you open it in Excel, you can save it as an Excel document.

Comment: Yes, except that I have a ton of these files so I can't do that manually

Comment: can you share a sample of what the xml file looks like?

Comment: What happens if you pass one to `readxl::read_excel`?

Comment: Updated, also what do you mean?

Comment: Oh yea no i did try passing it in to read_excel but it didn't work. it says it has to be xls or xlsx, i tried just changing the name to be .xlsx but then it said it's a zip file and cant be opened.